# the different tenses[present and past tense] in a sentence

Tags: tense

> The exercise books are returned now as the teacher corrected them.

I wanted to know whether I can use the different tenses [present and past tense] in a sentence.

Comment: Sure, why not? _'He **sat** here **reading** his book'_

Comment: @Varun KN you mean my example sentence is grammatical and natural.

Comment: can you share the source of this sentence?

Comment: Sorry.I have read it from a book,not on line.